# Linq to check before it creates select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query as follows

```
NOVId = (v.NOVId != null ? new List<int> { v.NOVId ?? default(int) }
: (from n in novs where n.Violations.Any(a => a.ViolationId == v.ViolationId) select v.NOVId ?? default(int)).ToList())
```

, what I want is, it is failing at n.Violations or a.ViolationId, since there are some novs which do not have violations, how can I fix this? that it shouldn't fail, just goes through without errors or exceptions - means this shhould select only if n.Violations has violations otherwise just return either 0 or null - any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: My guess is you're getting a null ref exception on `Violations` and if not then on a specific violation? You need more conditions or robust design.

Comment: I am getting null reference exception on nov.violations, yes either on all the violations or a specific violations, can you please help me in this regards - I really need help in this - thank you.

Comment: (from n in novs where n.Violations != null && n.Violations.Any(a => a.ViolationId == v.ViolationId) select v.NOVId ?? default(int)).ToList())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in the constructor of `Nov` you instantiate your enumeration.

```
public class Nov
{
    public Nov()
    {
        Violations = Enumerable.Empty<Violation>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Violation> Violations { get; }
}
```

So you know that there is always a reference to an empty enumeration of violations.

If it is a complex object or when the object is instantiated many times throughout the code or there are many different ways you can construct this object (you can also use the builder pattern here) you can also use a factory here the following way.

```
public class NovFactory
{
    public INov Create()
    {
        return new Nov
        {
            Violations = Enumerable.Empty<Violation>();
        }
    }
}

public interface INov
{
    IEnumerable<Violation> Violations { get; }
}

public class Nov : INov
{
    public IEnumerable<Violation> Violations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This nov object is coming from Entity Framework code first, I am not sure how is it implemented or even if its just returned from select, its an enumeration returned through select. So is there anyway I can check for the existence of violations on the Linq Query itself - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This construction `v.NOVId ?? default(int)` can be removed as there is no need to use `default(int)` as you've already checked `v.NOVId != null`:

```
var NOVIds = v.NOVId != null ? 
    new List<int> { v.NOVId }
  : (from n in novs where n.Violations.Any(a => a.ViolationId == v.ViolationId) 
        select v.NOVId).ToList()
```

**UPDATE:**

To check whether `a.ViolationId != null` and `v.ViolationId != null`, you can use the following query:

```
var NOVIds = v.NOVId != null ? 
    new List<int> { v.NOVId }
  : (from n in novs where n.Violations.Any(a => 
     (a.ViolationId != null && v.ViolationId != null) 
     ? (a.ViolationId == v.ViolationId) : false) 
        select v.NOVId).ToList()
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It is possible to use condition `n.Violations != null`, to check whether `n.Violations` is not null:

```
var NOVIds = v.NOVId != null ? 
    new List<int> { v.NOVId }
  : (from n in novs where n.Violations != null && n.Violations.Any(a => 
     (a.ViolationId != null && v.ViolationId != null) 
     ? (a.ViolationId == v.ViolationId) : false) 
        select v.NOVId).ToList()
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that, but is there no way I can check for the existence of violations on the Linq Query itself - thank you.

Comment: @SetUp thank you, but is there any way, if n.Violations itself comes as null, so any operation on it is failing? Any help for checking that out as well?

Comment: @Abdul I am glad to help you! :)